# CODECADEMY avg = get_class_average(students), I want to understand this, can someone explain to me?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
lloyd = {
  "name": "Lloyd",
  "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
  "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
  "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
  "name": "Alice",
  "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
  "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
  "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
 tyler = {
  "name": "Tyler",
  "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
  "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
  "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
 }

# Add your function below!
def average(numbers):
  total = sum(numbers)
  total = float(total)
  return total/len(numbers)

def get_average(student):
  homework = average(student["homework"])
  quizzes = average(student["quizzes"])
  tests = average(student["tests"])
  return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests

def get_letter_grade(score):
  if score >= 90:
    return "A"
  elif score >=80:
    return "B"
  elif score >=70:
    return "C"
  elif score >=60:
    return "D"
  else:
    return "F"

def get_class_average(class_list):
  results = []
  for student in class_list:
    student_avg = get_average(student)
    results.append(student_avg)
    return average(results)


students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

avg = get_class_average(students)
print(avg)
```

Comment: Hi Vincent. It's not at all clear what you're asking about. Just dumping a bunch of code and "Can somebody explain it" is not a valid question for Stack Overflow. You need to specify what exactly is confusing you about the line you have in mind. Do you understand assignment statements? Do you understand function calls? Can you reduce the issue to a much smaller set of code that still shows what you're confused about, without a lot of extra stuff you do understand?

Comment: After a quick visual inspection, this looks like a working piece of code.  Are you asking for an explanation about how it works?  You should be more specific about what part you don't understand.  It is very basic code.

Answer (score 0):

In python, functions are first-class objects in python. That `avg = function_name(args)` is storing the output of `function_name(args)` into the variable `avg`. But then, there are [python decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)... sigh, that's what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Neither the first-class nature of functions, nor the concept of decorators, have ANYTHING to do with this question.

Answer (score 0):

This code basically finds the average score of each student, then finds the average score among the average scores:

```
lloyd = {
  "name": "Lloyd",
  "homework": [90.0, 97.0, 75.0, 92.0],
  "quizzes": [88.0, 40.0, 94.0],
  "tests": [75.0, 90.0]
}
alice = {
  "name": "Alice",
  "homework": [100.0, 92.0, 98.0, 100.0],
  "quizzes": [82.0, 83.0, 91.0],
  "tests": [89.0, 97.0]
}
tyler = {
  "name": "Tyler",
  "homework": [0.0, 87.0, 75.0, 22.0],
  "quizzes": [0.0, 75.0, 78.0],
  "tests": [100.0, 100.0]
 }

def average(numbers): 
  total = sum(numbers) # Returns the sum of all in numbers in numbers
  total = float(total) # Convert integer to float
  return total/len(numbers) # Returns the average of the list

def get_average(student):
  homework = average(student["homework"]) # Student's average homework score
  quizzes = average(student["quizzes"]) # Student's average quiz score
  tests = average(student["tests"]) # Student's average test score
  return 0.1 * homework + 0.3 * quizzes + 0.6 * tests # Average score (10% homework, 30% quiz, 60% test)

def get_letter_grade(score): # returns appropriate letter for particular score
  if score >= 90:
    return "A"
  elif score >=80:
    return "B"
  elif score >=70:
    return "C"
  elif score >=60:
    return "D"
  else:
    return "F"

def get_class_average(class_list):
  results = []
  for student in class_list:
    student_avg = get_average(student) # Returns the student's average score
    results.append(student_avg) # Add to results list
    return average(results) # Return the average score among all the students


students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]

avg = get_class_average(students)
print(avg)
```